# Create link column contain two columns from another list sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

I have two SharePoint lists:

A - Invoices
B - Customer

In the invoices list I have created column lookup to customer name.

1. Is it possible to create one column in invoices that allows adding the customer's name by filer another column e.g. ID?

   I forgot the name of the client but I know that his ID is 13, I
   enter 13 and the name is added into one column.
2. I have the client's name written in capital letters, searching in lower case letters does not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please the following steps:**

1.Create two lists named "Customer" and "Invoices"

[image]

2.Go to the Invoices list and swith to **the classic mode**

3.Click on "**LIST**" tab and select "**Default New Form**"

[image]

4.Click "**Settings**" icon in the upper right corner and select "**Edit page**"

5.Click "**Add a Web Part**" link to add a **Script Editor** web part

[image]

6.On the Script Editor web part, click "**EDIT SNIPPET**" and apply this code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var IssueIDField = $("select[title='Customer ID']");
    IssueIDField.change(function(){
            Populate();
    });
});

var ListItem;

function Populate(){
    var IssID = $("select[title='Customer ID']").val();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var IssueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Customer');
    ListItem = IssueList.getItemById(IssID);
    clientContext.load(ListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Succed), Function.createDelegate(this,this.Failed));
}

function Succed(sender, args){
    $("input[title='Name']").val(ListItem.get_item("Title"));
}

function Failed(sender, args){
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
} 

</script>
```

7.Click **Stop Editing** and create new item in the Invoices list

[image]

Comment: Brillant, but is this possible to search Customer ID and Name Customer in one column list? Let`s say that i only want Title and Customer Name columns. We put ID or customer name in one form.

In customer list I made new column = CustomerName & ID. But search ID value still not working very well.

Comment: In my test, I cannot combine the ”Customer ID“ and ”Name“ value in one field. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!